# positioning a accordion menu with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, css-position

I want to implement an accordion menu in my web page. I know jQuery has many useful methods like `toggle()` and `slideDown()`, but as I understand all of these methods use the `display:hidden` CSS rule and cause the element to get hidden. Because of this, search engine spiders can't see them and some data of page will not be read by them.

I see that some designers use the `position` property to put these elements outside the view frame of page and to show the just change this property, but I don't know how to apply some effect like sliding to them.

Would you give me some approaches?

Comment: We do not know that search engine spiders do not crawl elements in which has the CSS property of display:hidden. Do you have a source for that statement? if you do I take back my comment

Comment: @RPM, no i have no statement that search engines company release it,i just read it on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User interface library called JQuery UI has a UI control called accordion: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/